# How to force to accept only numbers html input for Maui Blazor?

Tags: blazor, mudblazor, maui-blazor

I would like to prevent to type anything else only integers for .

I am using Maui Blazor with MudBlazor.
For regular Blazor on computer this works, but on phone does not.

```
<MudNumericField
    @bind-Value="value"
    Label="Standard"
    Variant="Variant.Text" 
    Min="0" 
    Max="10"
    Pattern="[0-9]" />

@code {
    int value = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i solved with these:

Razor.cs

```
private int? _integerValue;

[Inject]
public IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; } = default!;
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("mask");
    }
}
```

CustomMasks.js

```
window.mask = () => {
    const integerMask = {
        mask: Number,
        min: 0,
    };

    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".positive-integer input");
    elements.forEach(element => {
        IMask(element, integerMask);
    });
};
```

Razor:

```
<MudNumericField @bind-Value="_integerValue" Class="positive-integer"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the normal input tag you can just do this

```
<input type="number" inputmode="numeric"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still able to type "." and "-"